Airflow expand operator with
Based on the following answer when try to expand a SQLExecuteQueryOperator I've got the following error ValueError: expand() got an unexpected type 'SQLExecuteQueryOperator' for keyword argument 'element'.
Any advice, I've checked the documentation and try to google the error with no luck.
    @dag(start_date=pendulum.yesterday(),schedule_interval="@once")
def my_dag():
    get_all_locks = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(            
        task_id="get_all_locks",
        conn_id="postgres_user_interface",
        sql="/sql/locks/get.sql",        
    )

    @task
    def my_task(element):
        # do something with element
        result = element
        print(result)
        return result


    my_task.expand(element = get_all_locks)

dag = my_dag()


